# how to associate existing parent with child in django multitable inheritance

Tags: django, django-inheritance

I have an existing parent entity with many existing records:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=64, db_index=True)
```

I also have child objects that extend using django multi table inheritance:

```
class Investor(Entity):
    investor_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to create new Investor objects that maybe existing Entities.

How do I associate and create Investors with existing Entities?

Comment: Related Django ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7623

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a way you can do this like:

```
child = Restaurant(place_ptr=place)
child.save_base(raw=True)
```

You can view the full thread here:  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7623

Comment: It works except for time auto fields: you have to add them manually (= their values is not auto-generated)

Comment: In my experience `child` won't have the field values from the parent. `.refresh_from_db()` can fix it, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because

> multi-table inheritance uses an implicit OneToOneField to link the child and the parent

This means there is a one-to-one relationship between the **Entity** named record and the corresponding subclassed **Investor** models. Django just handles the translation of it from multiple tables to a single model so you don't really notice it.

So when you create a Investor you have to write the following line

```
Investor.objects.create(investor_name ='jone', name='entity name')
```

Which will create a Investor table row associated with a Entity row with one to one relationship. So if you want to create a new **Investor** object with that existing **Entity** record then database **one-to-one** relationship violation will be occurred and so far no any other association syntax in Django for multi inheritence.
For more details you can see [this link](https://godjango.com/blog/django-abstract-base-class-multi-table-inheritance/)

You can use existing Entity model record if your database design like below:

```
class Investor(models.Model):
  entity = model.ForeignKey(Entity) // Many-to-One relationship
  investor_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```