# Django model inheritance - creating child objects based on parent instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django 4.0

I have the following models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    # fields ommitted for the sake of brevity
    pass

class Child(Parent):
   child_only_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

#### code

```
p = Parent.objects.create(**fields_dict)
c1 = Child.objects.create(child_only_field='Hello 123', p) # Obviously won't work
# c2 = ...
```

Is there a way to create child objects from an instance of a parent (without manually "unpacking" the fields of the parent)?

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to unpack the parent's fields ? It looks like the best and simplest solution here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to associate existing parent with child in django multitable inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494664/how-to-associate-existing-parent-with-child-in-django-multitable-inheritance)

Answer (score 5):

it is easy, if you understand how Django works with implizit o2o relation.

```
class Parent(Model):
    # fields

# implizit o2o
class Child(Parent):
   child_only_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)

# explizit o2o
class Child_1(Parent):
  parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent)
  child_only_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

## How to save or create child with Implizit o2o relation.

1.Save child object by existed Parent class object **DON'T USE IT IN NORMAL CODE**.

```
parent = Parent.objects.get(pk=some_pk)
child = Child(child_only_field='Hello 123', pk=parent.pk)
child.save_base(raw=True) # important part of code
```

`Model.save_base` - internal method to save information only for child fields. BUT parent data should already exists.

2.Save created Parent as child. **DON'T USE IT IN NORMAL CODE**:

```
parent = Parent.objects.get(pk=some_pk)
parent.child_only_field = 'Hello 123'
parent.save_base(class=Child)
```

`Model.save_base` method saves information for whole chain of inheritance.

3.Save created child normally. **PLEASE USE IT IN NORMAL CODE**:

```
child = Child(child_only_field='Hello 123', **fields_dict)
child.save()
```

I especially don't use DataManager. I can say, this is more as internal method, than public interface.

4. Save child through DataManager.

   child = Child.objects.create(child_only_field='Hello 123', **fields_dict)

   `objects.create` made point 3. from my answer. You can see it in django.db.models.query.py

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The following 1-liner will produce a new field dictionary containing only shared fields, looping through Django's `_meta.fields` (does not include M2M fields), which you can then pass to the child instance.

```
p = Parent.objects.create(**fields_dict)

new_fields_dict = {f.name: getattr(p, f.name) for f in p._meta.fields
                   if f in Child._meta.fields and f != p._meta.pk}

c = Child.objects.create(child_only_field='Hello 123', **new_fields_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert fields of `p` to dict by `model_to_dict` and `p._meta.fields`.

```py
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class Parent(models.Model):
    # fields ommitted for the sake of brevity

    def fields_dict(self):
        return model_to_dict(
            p,
            fields=[
                field.name
                for field in self._meta.fields
                if field.name in self.__dict__
                and field.name != self._meta.pk.name
            ]
        )

class Child(Parent):
   child_only_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)

p = Parent.objects.create(**fields_dict)

c1 = Child.objects.create(child_only_field='Hello 123', **p.fields_dict())
```

It is also possible to overwrite `create` method.

```py
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'parent_obj' in kwargs:
            parent_fields = parent_obj.fields_dict()
        return super().create(*args, **kwargs, **parent_fields)

class Parent(models.Model):
    # fields ommitted for the sake of brevity

    def fields_dict(self):
        return model_to_dict(
            p,
            fields=[
                field.name
                for field in self._meta.fields
                if field.name in self.__dict__
                and field.name != self._meta.pk.name
            ]
        )

class Child(Parent):
    objects = MyManager()

    child_only_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    

p = Parent.objects.create(**fields_dict)

c1 = Child.objects.create(child_only_field='Hello 123', parent_obj=p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by assigning parent instance to child's `parent_ptr` attribute like:

```py
p = Parent.objects.create(**fields_dict)
c1 = Child.objects.create(child_only_field='Hello 123', parent_ptr=p)
```

But apparently you have to populate all the parent-specific fields as well, because Django will not propagate those values (which is an awkward behavior); And if there is a nullable field in parent model which is initialized in `fields_dict`, it will be reset after creating `c1` (also awkward). So maybe if you seek a way to only use a parent instance and nothing more, maybe there is no straightforward solution.

##### More details

By inheriting models by defining a model as a superclass, the tables will be created as followed:

[image: ER sample for models]

And the parent instance is accessible via `parent_ptr` attribute of the child instance, so you can assign it when creating the child as well like the above code, and doing `c1.parent_field = "Hello"` will also change its value in `Parent` table.